# Creating an RDD of edges from an RDD of graphs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Consider a collection of graphs. In my current case, it is an `RDD[Graph[VD, Double]]`, but it could with certain effort be reworked into `Seq[Graph[VD, Double]]`, if it would make an answer easier, but I prefer the former.

My question is, how to efficiently create an `RDD[Edge[Double]]` containing the edges of each of the graphs in the collection?

As an example, let the graph collection contain three graphs G1, G2 and G3. Let G1 have edge set {  e1, e2, e3 }, G2 have edge set {  e4, e5 } and G3 have edge set {  e6, e7, e8, e9 }. For an input RDD of graphs containing G1, G2 and G3, the output should be an `RDD[Edge[Double]]` containing { e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9 }.

First, I've tried with flatMap (`graphs.flatMap(graph => graph.edges)`), but I get a type mismatch error, stating that a TraversableOnce[?] type is required, but EdgeRDD[Double] found.

Further, I've tried first creating a collection of EdgeRDD[Double] with `graphs.map(graph => graph.edges)` with the intent of further modifying it, but it expectedly failed with 'Spark does not support nested RDDs'

Comment: As you noted Spark doesn't support nested RDDs, so you cannot have working `RDD[Graph[VD, Double]]`. And if you have `Seq[Graph[_, _]]` then just `map` and `union`

Answer (score -1):

Look at `.toLocalIterator`. This method allows you to turn `EdgesRDD` into `Iterable` and the `flatMap` will do the job.

Remember that this operation might be expensive. If your initial `RDD` of type `RDD[Graph[VD, Double]]` is not cached you should consider caching it. `toLocalIterator` would sequentially fetch every partition of `EdgesRDD`.

Your final call could look like this

```
graphs.flatMap(_.edges.toLocalIterator)
```

Comment: I will definitely analyze toLocalIterator. I'm not at my workstation, but I did a quick test in spark shell and graphs.flatMap(_.edges.toLocalIterator).collect returns an error (java.lang.NullPointerException with little discernible from the stack trace). Seems there might be a caveat with toLocalIterator.